# Filtering a Linq / Odata query over a 1 to many navigation property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services, linqpad

The following query works fine where I expand over a navigation property, **Schedules**, which has a *many to 1* relationship with the **AssociatedListing** property:

```
from la in ListingAssociations.Expand("AssociatedListing").Expand("AssociatedListing/Schedules")
where la.ListingId==60
select la
```

In the results, I can see multiple **Schedule** objects corresponding to each **AssociatedListing** object.  This is good.

However, when I try to add a filter on any of the **Schedules** fields:

```
from la in ListingAssociations.Expand("AssociatedListing").Expand("AssociatedListing/Schedules")
where la.ListingId==60 && la.AssociatedListing.Schedules.StartDate > DateTime.Today
select la
```

I get the error:

> "'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection' does not contain a definition for 'StartDate' and no extension method 'StartDate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection' could be found...".

So I guess the problem is that *StartDate* is a field of the **Schedule** class, and the "**Schedules**" navigation property is a collection of **Schedule** objects, hence `Schedules.StartDate` doesn't make any sense.  But there must be some way to specify a filter in this many to 1 situation.  How?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Change your **where** clause from this:

```
where la.ListingId==60 
   && la.AssociatedListing.Schedules.StartDate > DateTime.Today
```

To this:

```
where la.ListingId==60 
   && la.AssociatedListing.Schedules.All(x => x.StartDate > DateTime.Today)
```

If you want it so that any of the Schedules have a start date greater than today (instead of filtering to ones where all of them do), change `All` to `Any`.

Comment: unfortunately, Any and All are not supported by Odata / WCF data services.